# performance issue using dc.js and ui-router with tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dc.js

I'm using dc.js with angular.js's ui-router.
My goal is to have two routing states. Each should present multiple graphs.

Everything works fine, but everytime the routing state changes, the performance of the graphs gets slower. I think that the problem maybe is located on dc.js or my usage of it.

Everytime the routing state changes, new graphs will be invoked. Maybe dc.js doesn't delete the old ones. Is there an option in dc.js to delete the graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the undocumented `dc.chartRegistry.deregister(chart,group)`:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/src/core.js#L70

But a bigger performance hit is if you are creating dimensions or groups and not disposing of them:

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_dispose
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_dispose

This would cause more and more indices to be created, and all the data would have to get sorted  and binned in more and more ways.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to dispose all dimensions (according to the documentation this will also dispose every associated group). Unfortunately this didn't help. Now I'll try to deregister the charts. In the core.js there is also an .clear(group) method. Could I use this method to dispose all charts simultaneously?

Comment: Great! We need to document the chart registry; it's useful stuff.