# Disposing dc.js / crossfilter.js filters and groups between ajax calls to prevent memory and performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dc.js, crossfilter

I am having trouble with memory bloat and general slowness when rendering dc.js charts from repeated ajax calls. The chart renders fine for the first click, but additional clicks (to replace the charts with new data) progressively slow the charts down to a crawl. Memory usage does increase but the more likely culprit is that I'm having to joggle ever-increasing number of dimensions and groups.

I understand there is a [dispose() method](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_dispose) but I was wondering if there is a good way to dispose between ajax calls so the currently rendered charts are not deactivated.

Some pseudocode:

```
$("#id").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            A: A,
            B: B,
        }),
        success: function(d) {
            graphEverything(d);
        },
    });
}

function graphEverything(d) {
    var data = crossfilter(d);

    var x = data.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.A;
    });

    var xGroup = x.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
        return d.B;
    });

    dc.lineChart("#chart")
        .dimension(x)
        .group(xGroup);
};
```

The dimensions and groups seem to persist even after deregistering the charts like so.

```
dc.chartRegistry.clear();
```

Thanks

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128965/performance-issue-using-dc-js-and-ui-router-with-tabs)

Comment: I had a clickable data table and added a `.off('click')` and things seem to run smoothly. I have also added `.empty()` to each element to (hopefully) help with garbage collection. Then made sure the ajax calls don't overlap each other.

Comment: Unless you need to generate different charts with each ajax request, I would suggest only building the charts once, but replacing their dimensions and groups, and then disposing the old dimensions and groups.

Comment: That way you can just `redraw` and not re-`render` on each event. Much more efficient and will provide transitions.